# Select fields from eager loaded model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to use the select() filter to get columns both from the main Model and the related model, which I'm loading with the with() function, but I haven't found a general answer on how this should work.
The output of this should be a list which can be loaded in a select2 component.

Let's say I have two models, Province and Country, and Province has a foreign key on Country (country_id); in the Model this relationship is described with belongsTo (Province->country()) and hasMany (Country->provinces()).
This works, but I don't like it because it's not the pure Eloquent solution (the output array is called $data):

```php
    $result = Province::with('country')
    ->where ( 'provinces.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%' )
    ->limit(25)
    ->get();
    foreach ($result as $res) {
        $data[] = ['id' => $res->id, 'text' => $res->name." - ".$res->country->name];
    }
```

This works but it creates an array with a nested object for each row

```php
    $result = Province::with('country')
    ->where ( 'provinces.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%' )
    ->limit(25)
    ->get();
```

This doesn't because it can't find the column country.name

```
    $result = Province::with('country')
    ->where ( 'provinces.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%' )
    ->limit(25)
    ->select('provinces.id', DB::raw('CONCAT(provinces.name," ", country.name) AS text'))
    ->get();
```

I also tried with the select/addSelect in the anonymous function in the with(), as I read in other answers.
What's the correct way to have the array with the combined fields from the parent and child Model?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use a `join()` clause to query for/select from any `country` columns.

Comment: Uhm, but that's from the query builder, not from Eloquent. Since I use the Eloquent models I thought I didn't need explicit joins (also the DB::raw think it's tied to the mysql I'm using right now...)

Comment: `join()` is still required for things like this. Yes, the point of Eloquent is to avoid having to do this, but if you don't want a nested property, then you need to use `join()`. Or, you can define a resource that collapses `country.name` onto the base model (available via `$result->country_name` or similar), but I'm not too familiar with that approach.

Comment: Adding ```->leftJoin('countries', 'provinces.country_id', '=', 'countries.id')``` as I'm used in the query builder works as expected,..I'll research more on the second approach as well, thanks :)

Comment: No problem! Feel free to add a self-answer and accept it (when the system allows) to properly close this question. Cheers!